# autoNumeric jQuery plugin without separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I would like to find the way to use this plugin without (comma) separator. Any idea?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.auto').autoNumeric('init', {vMin: '0', vMax: '999999999'});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, first try to use the `v4` version found in the `next` branch currently (it'll soon be released in `master`).

*This will allow you to drop the jQuery dependency.*

In order to remove the comma group separator, you just need to do :

```
const anElement = new AutoNumeric('.auto', {
    minimumValue : '0',
    maximumValue : '999999999',
    decimalPlaces : 0,
    digitGroupSeparator : '',
}`
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Also, if that answer your problem, please validate this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: I was using v1.9 and I resolved the problem with aSep: ''

Comment: Exactly, `aSep` is the old name for `digitGroupSeparator` (see [the code](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/blob/ed409f78f21ca43e7bc56386fbd2573cb37abe34/src/AutoNumeric.js#L7677)). The options I provided are still valid, and updated with the new option names. If that answered your problem (which it seems it did looking at your first comment), then please *accept* that answer (with the green checkmark) so that other users will know this is a working answer. Thanks!